# Can I tell which global node dependencies my app is using?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm deploying my first app to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk and it's failing to run as some of the dependencies on my dev machine have been installed locally and so are missing from my app'#s node_module folder than I have uploaded to AWS.

Is there a way to tell which dependencies my app is using that are not in package.json or node_modules?

Thanks

Comment: Why you are not able to add your local project dependecies at `package.json` ? Isn't it a part of `npm`?

Comment: As part of getting up to speed with node over a few months it seems I have added some globally , which only became apparent upon deployment. I was hoping to get a list so I don't have to add them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command on your terminal `npm list -g --depth=0`. It will return all globally installed modules and then you can manually check which ones you require on your project.

Answer (score 0):

As a rough first round info gathering you can find all modules you require in your project with a simple `grep`:

```
grep -R --exclude-dir node_modules --include '*.js' require .
```

To extract just the module names and remove duplicates you can pipe the result through `cut` and `sort`:

```
 grep -R --exclude-dir node_modules --include '*.js' require . |
     cut -d '(' -f2 |
     cut -d "'" -f2 |
     sort -u
```

You can then filter the result and only print what's globally installed by comparing it with the output of `npm list -g`. The `comm` command comes in handy:

```
grep -R --exclude-dir node_modules --include '*.js' require . |
    cut -d '(' -f2 |
    cut -d "'" -f2 |
    sort -u > required.txt

npm list -g --depth=0 2> /dev/null |
    grep @ |
    cut -d ' ' -f2 |
    cut -d@ -f1 |
    sort -u > global_install.txt

comm -1 -2 required.txt global_install.txt
```